# How can I limit the download from internet

Tags: parental-controls, network-monitoring

I have a local network which use router to connect to Internet. However, I want to limit the download source from internet. How can I block some download address for user. Because some software user download may carried some not pornographic messages. Do I need to set something in the router. Or there is some software can do it (better free and open source)

Thanks

Comment: Ah, the old "block everything but porn" question... *"Because some software user download may carried some **not** pornographic messages"*. Or maybe that's a humorous typo...

Answer (score 0):

Usually the better routers can do this. What model do you have? You might find the answer in manual to your device.

Another option is to "fake" invalid address for the blocked sites in Hosts file on the computer, assuming the user is not particularly tech-savvy this will help.

If you are using a software firewall, it might also offer this as a feature.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Windows, so using **Windows "Parental Controls"** (called **"Family Safety"** in Windows 8/8.1) to limit a user's access might be what you're looking for.

- [c|net - How to use parental controls in Windows 8](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-parental-controls-in-windows-8/) - *"After creating a new account with Family Safety turned on, you'll automatically be taken to the Family Safety setup section in the Control Panel"*
- [Set up Family Safety - Windows 8.1/RT8.1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/set-up-family-safety#set-up-family-safety=windows-8)

  > Family Safety helps you set limits on your child's PC time, as well as the websites, apps, and games they can use (and when). To set up Family Safety, you'll need to sign in with an administrator account. Before you get started, make sure that each child you want to monitor has a standard user account or a child's account. Family Safety is turned on automatically if you create a child's account, but it can be turned on later on standard accounts. For more info about user accounts, see [Create a user account](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-user-account) and [User accounts: FAQ](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/user-accounts-frequently-asked-questions).

Answer (score 0):

There are ways for doing it depending upon the router and Operating System you running and your background. If your operating system is Unix based system like Linux or Mac then you can add filters in IP-Table to block the sites. There is firewalls available on all the systems you need to configure it as per your need. There are some add-ons to the browsers that will block the desired website.

In spite of above there are some software that can do these things for you easily like Hello Spy, Norton family, DNS Angel, Bit defender Parental control, Net Nanny, web watcher etc. These are easy gui tools(software) that can do the parental control. They may or may not be free.

In latest windows 8 series there is application Family Safety that can be configured to do so but it is for windows 8 onwards only.